# How get the HTML code as a string in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I want to do something special. I have already implemented to show the table when clicking a button. Now I want When I click a separate button I want to get a table HTML code of that table.

Code for show table:

```
res.render('quote-quick-view', {
  'menu': utils.getMenu('/quotes', req.session.username),
  'user': req.session.username,
  'currencies': currencies,
  'currenciesMap': JSON.stringify(getCurrenciesMap(currencies)),
  'configurationsMap': JSON.stringify(getConfigurationsMap(quote.configurations)),
  'configurations': quote.configurations,
});
```

Using the above `res.render` I can show the table in `quote-quick-view.handlebars`. I want to know how can I get table HTML code  assign to a variable without showing the table( purpose of this to send HTML code to Pipedrive).